# Python path string adds an extra slash except for the last one

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a path to a directory where I want to iterate over all of the files. It looks like this `myPath = "D:\workspace\test\main\test docs"` and when I print out myPath it looks like `"D:\\workspace\test\\main\test docs"` . As you can see it added a slash to every slash except the last one.

When I do `for path, dirs, files in os.walk(myPath):` it doesn't work if there isn'
t the extra slash. Why isn't python adding the extra slash to the last slash?

It was working on a different computer.

Comment: try `myPath = r"D:\workspace\test\main\test docs"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because **`'\t'` is an escape sequence that makes sense**: it is a **tab**, like is specified in the [2.4.1 *String literals* section](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html). The others only happen not to make sense here, so Python will escape these for you (for free).

You can thus add the extra *backslash* like:

```
myPath = "D:\\workspace\\test\\main\\test docs"
```

or you can use a **raw string**, by prefixing it with `r`:

```
myPath = r"D:\workspace\test\main\test docs"
```

In that case:

> Unless an **`r' or`R' prefix** is present, escape sequences in strings are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard C.

So that means the backslash (`\`) is *not* interpreted as something special, but only as a backslash.